# why after the exit(0) is called, but the child process still remains?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, exit

in the parent process I want to start a daemon to do a long time work, so I use
the double fork() to create the grandchild process to start the daemon. The question is
every once in a while, the child process does not exit successfully, I am sure that
the printf() before the exit(0) is called, but when I use the "ps" I can see the child process
pid listed, and it never exit. Do you know why this happened, should I call _exit(0) instead of
exit(0) to make the child process exit?

```
startProcess(const char *pidfile, const char *command)
    pid_t   pid;
    char    cmd[1024];
    char    *head = cmd;
    char    *end;
    char    *argv[128] = {0};
    int     argc = 0;

    if( 0 == (pid=fork()) ) { //fork a child 
        if( 0 > setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, 0) ) {
            perror();
            return;
        }
        pid = fork(); //fork a grandchild
        if(-1 == pid){
            exit(-1);
        }else if(0 == pid){ //grandchild process
            if (snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "%s", command) <= sizeof(cmd) - 1) {
                /* change command line to argc/argv format */
                do {
                    if (argc >= sizeof(argv)/sizeof(argv[0]) - 1)
                        break;
                    for (; (*head == ' ' || *head == '\t'); head++); //remove space or TAB in the header
                    if (*head == '\0')
                        break;
                    if (NULL != (end = strpbrk(head, " \t"))) {
                        *end = '\0';
                        argv[argc++] = head;
                        head = end + 1;
                    } else {
                        argv[argc++] = head;
                        break;
                    }
                } while (1);
                argv[argc] = NULL; // Maximal value of argc is ARRAY_SIZE(argv) - 1.

                /* execute command to start a daemon*/
                execvp(argv[0], argv);
           }
           //should not enter here
           exit(-1);
        }else{ //still in child process
            printf("child process exit\n");
            exit(0); //child process exit, but sometimes this call seems fail
        }
    }else if(-1 == pid){
        return;
    }else{ //parent process
        int     status = 0;
        int     rv
        pid_t   r_pid = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
        if (pid == r_pid) {
            if (WIFEXITED(status) && (0 == WEXITSTATUS(status))) {
                rv = 0;
            } else {
                rv = -1;
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }
```

Comment: It's probably in zombie state. Show the `ps` output so we can confirm.

Comment: Read [advanced linux programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

Using `WNOHANG` instead of `0` is surely wrong. If the parent calls `waitpid` (with `WNOHANG`) before the child exits, the child will remain in existence as a zombie waiting to be reaped until the parent exits too.

Comment: I used to use "0" in the waitpid instead of WNOHANG, the result is the parent process is hang at the waitpid, It seems that the child process does not trigger the SIG_CHLD to parent, in other word, the exit(0) is not successfully called. the point is the child process does not exit, it is not the point that child process exit but not reaped by the parent

Comment: SIGCHLD is ignored by default. If you change that, you can't use `waitpid` outside of the signal handler.